# I am a physicist with a difficult equation (quadratic exponential) I am curious about. No luck with a lit review, sympy or Mathematica.

Tags: functions, problem-solving, transcendental-equations

I have an equation I have been playing with (the variable is $x$ and the constants are positive and real):

$$( r_1 - x )^2 \frac{  a  r_3  e^{x / r_2} + b  r_2  e^{x / r_3} }{\left( a  e^{ x / r_2} + b  e^{ x / r_3} \right)^2} = k.$$

Certain approximations can lead to an equation that looked better to me.

It has the form $e^{2 x} +ae^x = bx +c $ where the symbols no longer have the same meaning. Without the $e^{2x}$ term I can find the solution easily with Lambert's W and it might be good enough for my purposes.

Does anyone have experience with equations like these? Do you know of a resource that might show lots of examples of the W function in action? Or, do you have a reason why an analytical solution here is not reasonable and I should just settle for the numerical approach?

What branch of advanced algebra would govern these kinds of problems? Any tips on keywords for my research? Like I said I'm a physicist and don't necessarily know the math search terms to use.

Comment: I have edited your equation, please check it's correctness, if by mistake I have edited something wrong.

Comment: What about for very small $x$ whereby you may approximate the exponential using a Taylor expansion?

Comment: The equation is transcendental, thus can only be solved numerically. There are many sources you can read about the W function. Even Wikipedia has a few examples on the page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @Kevin, x in the first equation is near r2 or r3 and can in principle be bigger or smaller. I can do a piecewise expansion (for <1 and >1) but this isn't really what I'm after and I have to keep lots of terms. In the second case, $e^{2x}$ is small and I can drop that term and solve in terms of LambertW.

Comment: @MeeSeongIm Thank you for your edits.

Comment: In $e^{2 x} +a e^x = bx +c$, are $(a,b,c)$ all positive ?

Answer (score 0):

[Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) gives:
$$e^{2x}+a e^x=bx+c\iff -\frac cb+\frac1be^x+\frac{e^{2x}}{b}=u+ve^x+we^{2x}=x=u+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(ve^x+we^{2x})^n\bigg|_u$$

therefore:

$$x=-\frac cb+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(k+n)^{n-1}\left(\frac ab\right)^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)! b^k e^{-(k+n)\frac cb}}$$

usually gives the root further from $0$ [shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%3D-2%2B0.3+e%5Ex%2B0.7+e%5E%282x%29) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-2.0%2Bsum%5Bsum%5B0.7%5Ek+0.3%5E%28n-k%29%2F%28k%21+%28n-k%29%21%29+e%5E%28%28k+%2B+n%29+%28-2%29%29+%28k+%2B+n%29%5E%28n-1%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C10%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D). If both sums go to $\infty$, then they are interchangeable. For the other root closer to $0$, of 3 possible roots try:

$$e^{2x}+a e^x=bx+c\mathop\iff^{e^x=t} t=\frac ca+\frac ba\ln(t)+rt^2=p+q\ln(t)+rt^2=t\implies x=\ln\left(p+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}(q\ln(t)+rt^2)^n\bigg|_p\right)$$

could be a triple series using binomial theorem and  [Stirling S1 summation](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/). Let us know if you want this triple sum solution